# JFrame without frame border, maximum button, minimum button and frame icon

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create a without frame border, maximum button, minimum button and frame icon.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Call `setUndecorated(true)` on your `JFrame`.

This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable (see [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)).

[image]

Comment: Ok.I will set an answer is a accepted answeri fi it solve my problem.Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: How can I make a frame is not displayable?
I have created JFrame and added some controls to it by using Netbeans. 
In main function I code: MyJframe form = new MyJframe();
form.setUndecorated(true);
form.setVisible(true);
But it throw exception

Comment: @Chan - Does the MyJFrame constructor call pack()? That would make the JFrame displayable

Comment: @Chan Pye: Put `setUndecorated(true);` at the beginning of your constructor `MyJframe()`.

Answer (score 7):

This code Explains how you can achieve it.

Note: setUndecorated(true); statement in the constructor.

You cannot undecorate the Frame while it is already displayed.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);

}
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MyFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));


    /* important Statement */
    setUndecorated(true);
}
```

}

[image: Frame without Border]

Answer (score 2):

Inside the constructor you can put code setUndecorated(true) it will disappear Frame.

For example:
//This is constructor

```
public freak() {    
    super("Images");
    panel = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\shilu.shilu-PC\\Desktop\\2.jpg");
    label = new JLabel(image);
    add(panel);
    add(label);

    //Main thing is this one
    setUndecorated(true);
    //Just add this code in your constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the `java.awt.Window` class. A `Window` is like a `JFrame`, but with no borders.

Note that the `Window` class constructor needs a `Frame` (`java.awt.Frame`) as an argument, but you can set it to `null`. You can also extend the `Window` class to customize it like this:

```
public class MyWindow extends Window{
   public MyWindow(){
      super(null); // creates a window with no Frame as owner
      setBounds(x, y, width, height);
      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

In `main`, you can create an instance of `MyWindow` instead of `Window`.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Window window = new MyWindow();
    // Other stuff in main
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note 2 things:  1)  This question has the `swing` tag applied.  2) Swing provides a `JWindow`.  If you delete or (preferably) edit your answer, you might avoid some down votes on it.  ;)

Comment: Window or Jwindow does not support certain mouse events and it does not have taskbar control.

Answer (score 0):

Use method frame.getContentPane();
this method return inside content of any frame.
But you need to cast it into a JPanel.
PrintUI using JPanel not JFrame....